# Derived class ignores base class functions

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am working on a homework assignment about inheritance in C++ and I am having trouble understanding why this is happening in my code. I have a Triangle class derived from a Figure class and the program is not  running the way I am expecting it to. In the Main.cpp file, a Triangle object is created and the `draw()` function is invoked, I expected this function to call the one defined in figure.cpp but instead it seems to be calling the one defined in triangle.cpp. I thought this was only the case when a function is defined with the keyword `virtual`?

For the assignment, I have to find the output of the program for two scenarios: One is using the keyword `virtual` and the other is when not using the keyword `virtual`. My program right now has the same output for both cases. I have implemented the functions by printing out a statement to show which version of the function is called. I believe that this is the correct way to redefine a function in the derived class.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "figure.h"
#include "triangle.h"

using std::cout;

int main()
{
  Triangle tri;

  //This function should invoke the one from figure.cpp
  tri.draw();  

  return 0;
}
```

figure.h

```
#ifndef _FIGURE_H_
#define _FIGURE_H_
#include <iostream>

class Figure {
    public: 
        Figure();

        void draw();
        void erase();
        void center();  

};

#endif
```

figure.cpp

```
#include "figure.h"

Figure::Figure() {

}

void Figure::draw() {
    std::cout << "Calling Figure::draw()" << std::endl;
}

void Figure::erase() {
    std::cout << "Calling Figure::erase()" << std::endl;
}

void Figure::center() {
    std::cout << "Calling Figure::center()" << std::endl;
}
```

triangle.h

```
#ifndef _TRIANGLE_H_
#define _TRIANGLE_H_
#include <iostream>
#include "figure.h"

class Triangle : public Figure {
    public:

        Triangle();

        void draw();

        void erase();

        void center();  
    private:

        double base;
        double height;
        double centerPoint;


};

#endif
```

triangle.cpp

```
#include "triangle.h"
Triangle::Triangle() {

    base = 0.0;
    height = 0.0;
    centerPoint = 0.0;

}

void Triangle::draw() {
    std::cout << "Calling Triangle::draw()" << std::endl;
}

void Triangle::erase() {
    std::cout << "Calling Triangle::erase()" << std::endl;
}

void Triangle::center() {
    std::cout << "Calling Triangle::center()" << std::endl;
}
```

***UPDATE**

I have created another program that does not use separate compilation and it is giving me what I expect. Why does separate compilation lead to a  different outcome? Below is the code that I am testing which doesn't use separate compilation. Calling `draw()` in main invokes the function defined in Figure and the one in Triangle is called if I uncomment the function declaration.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Figure {

    public:
        Figure() {

        }

        void draw() {
            cout << "Calling Figure::draw()" << endl;
        }

};

class Triangle : public Figure {
    public:
        Triangle() {

        }

//      void draw() {
//          cout << "Calling Triangle::draw()" << endl;
//      }



};


int main () {

    Triangle tri;

    tri.draw();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The output that you are seeing is the correct one. If you want to test for polymorphism, you should try calling the function from a base class pointer pointing to a derived class or a base class reference to a derived class.
Try : Figure & tri = Triangle(); OR Figure * tri = new Triangle(); and call draw of tri.

Comment: @sajas I was given the main.cpp file and I have to use this to test the program I wrote. Part of the question asked me to observe and describe the differences in the output when the `virtual` was used and not used. I also had to explain why using `virtual` would lead to such differences and that's why I assumed the output should be different.

Comment: My other was comment was a bit inaccurate. I meant to say that when you have an object type, and you call a method on that object, the call is resolved using the static type of the object (in this case `Triangle`). Dynamic or virtual dispatch occurs when you have a `virtual` function that is overridden, and you're calling it through a derived class pointed to or referenced by a base class pointer/reference. In that case the class is resolved using the dynamic type of the pointer/reference. Read Justin's answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

`Triangle` inherits the `draw` function from `Figure`.

This means that, if you removed the declaration of `void draw();` from `Triangle`, you would *still* be able to invoke `tri.draw()` within the `main` function, and it would invoke `Figure::draw`.

However, when you *do* declare `void draw();` within `Triangle`, it actually **replaces** the `draw` function that was inherited from `Figure`, and makes it as if you never inherited it from `Figure` at all.

Therefore, if you want it to invoke the `draw` function from `Figure`, one option is to *not* replace it within Triangle.

Another option would be to have `Triangle::draw` manually invoke `Figure::draw` within the function body of `Triangle::draw`.

The keyword `virtual` does something different: it allows the reverse effect to happen.
Suppose you declared:

```
Figure & f = tri;
f.draw();
```

For all the compiler can tell, `f` is a reference to a Figure, and could reference ANY figure of any type.
However, in such a case, if the `draw` functions was declared as `virtual`, it would allow the program to determine at run-time exactly what type of figure `f` references, thereby allowing the program to invoke the right version of `draw` for any given reference to any derived type of `Figure`.

Comment: When I remove the declaration of `void draw()`, I get an error saying "undefined reference to Triangle::draw()". It doesn't seem to be inheriting the `draw()` from Figure. Also I am not allowed to edit the main.cpp file.

Comment: That's because you still have the function `Triangle::draw()` in your triangle.cpp. Remove that as well. Now there is ONLY Figure::draw(). So any calls to Triangle::draw() will be invoking Figure::draw().

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is doing the right thing:
`tri.draw();` should execute `Triangle::draw()`.

`Triangle::draw()` is called because the type (`Triangle`) is known. As a nonvirtual function, the compiler chooses the correct function to call at compilation. This is called *static dispatch*. The other option is at runtime, and is called *dynamic dispatch*.

So the first part is to figure out the syntax to call `Figure::draw()` using `tri`. Your code appears to need no changes, apart from the line: `tri.draw();`

The second part is to figure out how to work with dynamic dispatch, and you will need to modify your `Figure`s.

I'm stopping there, since this is homework.

Comment: I am not allowed to change the main.cpp file since it was given to test the rest of the program I wrote. I think I may have implemented the other parts wrong. I am thinking that the when I do not use `virtual` functions, the function that gets called is the one in the base class, and when I do use `virtual` the function that gets called should be the derived class. Would it be possible to change anything besides main.cpp to do that? Since my assignment asks to explain why using `virtual` would lead to "such differences".

Comment: I am not sure, the instructions were to implement the classes using separate compilation and test it using the main.cpp file. The reason why I redefined the `draw()` was so that I could tell which version of the function was being called.

Comment: @Steven - You declared a `Triangle`, you get `Triangle` stuff.  Doesn't matter if the function you're calling is virtual or not.  It is when you declare a pointer (or reference) to a base class, and then assign the address of a derived class does `virtual` come into play.

Comment: @Steven well, if you need another result, the instructor may be looking for a solution which involves using another function name and *that* function may be called from `draw` - i.e. the `Figure` implementation calls a virtual function of another name (e.g. `virtual dyn_draw()`). in that case, the only `draw` would be in `Figure`.

Comment: @justin I have updated my original post with a test program which doesn't use separate compilation and it gives me what I think the correct answer should be. Why does separate compilation result in different behavior?